# Pass in self when I initiate the class

Tags: ruby

When I call `A.new` inside of `B`, is there a way to automatically get certain objects without specifying it? I want to pass `self` from `B` into `A` automatically without specifying it.

```
class A
  initialize object=target-self
  end
end


class B
  A.new
end
```

Then, I don't have to type this every time I want `self` to be passed in default unless I specify another class.

```
 A.new self
```

Comment: If you need to pass caller to the constructor so often it would bother you, perhaps you could find a better way to organize your classes? What are you trying to do with this? BTW, there are couple of questions on SO similar to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116525/sender-class-in-ruby http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614470/how-to-retrieve-caller-context-object-in-ruby etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is straightforward. All you have to do is write:

```
class A
  def initialize(object = self)
    # work with object
  end
end
```

There is always a value for `self` in Ruby. In the example you provided, it will evaluate to the `B` class. To get it to be an instance of the class, just call the method during initialization:

```
class B
  def initialize
    A.new  # self is a B instance here
  end
end
```