# ruby pass self of caller of method into method being called automaticly

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to create a method that passes the caller as the default last argument. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9953511/pass-in-self-when-i-initiate-the-class?answertab=oldest#tab-top), I only need:

```
class A
  def initialize(object = self)
    # work with object
  end
end
```

so that in:

```
class B
  def initialize
    A.new  # self is a B instance here
  end
end
```

`self` will be `B` rather than `A`;

However, this doesn't seem to work. Here's some test code:

```
class A
    def self.test test, t=self
        puts t
    end
end

class B
    def test test,t=self
        puts t
    end
end

class T
    def a
        A.test 'hey'
    end
    def b
        B.new.test 'hey'
    end
    def self.a
        A.test 'hey'
    end
    def self.b
        B.new.test'hey'
    end
end
```

and I get:

```
T.new.a # => A
T.new.b # => #<B:0x000000015fef00>
T.a     # => A
T.b     # => #<B:0x000000015fed98>
```

whereas I expect it to be `T` or `#<T:0x000000015fdf08>`. Is there a way to set the default last argument to the caller?

EDIT:

```
class Registry
    class << self
        def add(component, base=self)
            self.send(component).update( base.to_s.split('::').last => base)
        end
    end
end
```

The idea is pretty simple, you would use it like this

```
class Asset_Manager
    Registry.add :utilities
end
```

and you access it like:

```
include Registry.utilities 'Debugger'
```

I'm trying to de-couple classes by having a middle-man management type class that takes care of inter-class communications, auto-loading of missing classes and erroring when it doesn't exist, it works but I just want to be able to use the above rather than:

```
class Asset_Manager
    Registry.add :utilities, self
end
```

It just feels cleaner, that and I wanted to know if such a thing was possible.

Comment: I'm asking a legitimate question, I'm sorry if it's a little complicated, but  downvoting or trying to close the question without at least saying why is completely unhelpful;  I think it's reasonably clear what I'm asking and thanks to some one's edit even clearer. If it can't be done, fine, say so, don't just go CLOSE without saying anything. I want to know if this can be done as it would make my code more concise and easier to use if it can be.

Comment: Could you please put bracket around methods it is actually quite readable that way

Comment: This can't be done the way you want it. If this will somehow improve your code, the improvement will be purely cosmetic, I think. The underlying problems will remain: too interconnected classes. Why on earth should methods in `A` get an implicit reference to `T`? Why can't this functionality be in `T` directly? And so on, and so forth.

Comment: It wouldn't be Implicit to `T`, it would be implicit to any caller of the method, the reason Is that I'm doing this to decouple classes (as paradoxical as it sounds). Originally I had it so you include `A` as a module and the `included` hook would fire and add a reference of the child class to itself in an instance varb array, but that won't work any more (for reasons that would take a bit more explaining and are pretty much irrelevant to this issue). So now I want to use a method, that will do almost the same thing, just call the method and a reference to self gets passed automatically.

Comment: @Thermatix: yes, I meant the caller object, of course. :) This example code is useless. You want to do X, yet you ask how to do Y. Post the X (meaning, "what are you _really_ trying to do here? Post the real shit")

Comment: **whereas I expect it to be T or #<T:0x000000015fdf08>** what do you expect ?

Comment: @Anony-mouse: he expects `t = self` default parameters to evaluate to `T` or instance of `T` (the caller object)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It is actually quite unreadable can you just explain a little bit more.So far as i see it 'Class T' is not understandable

Comment: I added actual code rather than just test code which should add some context and make it a bit easier to understand. @Anony-mouse: I expect it to be a reference to the `T` class or an Instance of `T`, the caller of the method rather than the the object the method is being called on.

Comment: We are good to go now

Comment: @Thermatix: I read your code and I have to say: what you're trying to do is not an improvement. It is converting an obvious explicit dependency into an implicit one. It hinders comprehension of the code, etc. Your `Registry.add` is a typical "set value" method. For it you need a key _and_ a value. `Registry.add :utility, self` is very clear. `Registry.add :utility` is very unclear. Add a symbol, wtf? What is really going on here? Imagine another developer (even yourself in 6 months) trying to understand this.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with you if not for the fact that the second argument will never be anything other than a reference to the caller, otherwise it breaks the purpose of the method. Still, if it can't be done then it can't be done and there's not much I can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't escape the explicit `self`. But you can hide it with some ruby magic.

```
class Registry
  def self.add(group, klass)
    puts "registering #{klass} in #{group}"
  end
end


module Registrable
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def register_in(group)
      Registry.add(group, self)
    end
  end
end

class AssetManager
  include Registrable

  register_in :utilities
end
# >> registering AssetManager in utilities
```

Comment: Clever, very clever, almost but not quite, still It did answer the question best so you get the cookie! I'm just going to have to accept I have to pass in `self`, shame but never mind. P.s. I changed `add` to be `add_to` to make it a bit more obvious, though I'm thinking of doing  `VCK::Registry.add self, to: :root`

Comment: Yeah, that last one seems like the best. Go with it. :)

Comment: which is funny as I'm trying to reduce verbosity XD.

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

Ruby resolves the default arguments in the context of the **receiver**. That is, the object before the `.` in a method call. What you called the *receiver* should be the caller, actually.

```
class A
  def test1(value = a)
    puts a
  end
  def test2(value = b)
    puts b
  end
  def a
    "a"
  end
end

a = A.new
a.test1 #=> a
def a.b; "b" end
a.test2 #=> b
```

If I were you, I would use the `extended` (or `included`) hook, where both the extending class and the extended module can be accessed. You can program what ever logic you want based on the information.

```
module Registry
  module Utilities
    def self.extended(cls)
      #puts cls
      ::Registry.send(component).update( cls.to_s.split('::').last => cls)
    end
  end
end

class Asset_Manager
  extend Registry::Utilities
end
```

Comment: for the record, I did call it caller, some else changed it to receiver, I kind of didn't notice either :P, any way ,I was using what your doing before, only I did with `included` rather than `extended` but as I said, this can't be used any more.